# Convert date to unix timestamp through jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to check whether the entered dob is above 18th old. For that i want to convert to convert the entered date to the unix time stamp. I tried using:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('@', $('#dob').val());
```

But it gives three additional zeros and also goes one day earlier. Like for "10/10/1967" it returns: -70369200000 while it should return: -70329600. How should i change it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the Unix time out of a date picker use:

```
$(el).datepicker('getDate') / 1000;
```

However you should also note that the semantics of `Date` objects are not well defined for "negative" dates.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't solve the previous day issue. 10/12/1967 returns -70196400 while according to http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm it should return -70156800

Comment: It's like the datepicker conversion is always 11 hours earlier

Comment: aaah wait, now that i think of it, it must be because of the time difference. timestamp is relative and not universal